# Why is the size of my Github archive double of Github release?

Tags: git, github

What is the difference between an archive and a release (codeload).

This url:

- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/archive/v0.23.4.tar.gz = 12.6MB
- https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v0.23.4/yarn-v0.23.4.tar.gz = 3.8MB
- https://api.github.com/repos/yarnpkg/yarn/tarball/v0.23.4 = 12.6MB

What is the difference? Some tools are telling me I can download a release using the github API (codeload stuff) but the size is not the same for those tar.gz?

The problem is I can not download the 'small' release using the API.

Comment: Download the archives, unpack them, compare their content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small file does not contain the entire test suite or its fixtures. That is what takes most of the space.

```
$ du -sh __tests__
26M __tests__
```

This is because the two large files are more or less packaging up the repository itself for download, whereas the release bundle is a built artifact that only contains the release code. It is produced by [scripts/build-dist.sh](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/scripts/build-dist.sh). It doesn't contain any of the tests, because those are not needed in the (already tested) release distribution.

If you want to fetch this from Github using the API, something like this should work.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import requests
import shutil

headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}

author_name = "yarnpkg"
repo_name = "yarn"
tag_name = "v0.23.4"

download_path = "/tmp/{}-{}.tar.gz".format(repo_name, tag_name)

# To get latest release, sub in this URL instead:
# /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/latest
r = requests.get(
    "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/releases/tags/{}".format(
        author_name,
        repo_name,
        tag_name,
    ),
    headers=headers)

if r.status_code == 200:
    json_response = r.json()
    for asset in json_response["assets"]:
        if asset["name"] == "{}-{}.tar.gz".format(repo_name, tag_name):
            download_url = asset["browser_download_url"]
            print("Downloading to {}".format(download_path))
            r2 = requests.get(download_url, stream=True)
            with open(download_path, "wb") as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(r2.raw, out_file)
            print("Download complete.")
else:
    print('ERROR: GitHub response code {} unexpected.'.format(
        r.status_code
    ))
```

You can read more about this in the [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/).

I guess you can use the git data API to get the full contents of the repo ... but it's probably a lot easier to just use git clone at that point?

Comment: Thanks, it's still a bit sad you can only download the release including a testset with the github api

Comment: @DenCowboy I updated my answer with an example for release API download... easy to adapt for other endpoints found in docs. There is a "full source" API endpoint that may do what you are after (I didn't try it). https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link